cómo instalar xdebug en windows 11, xampp y visual studio code con extensión php debug que no funciona
Failed loading C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
PHP 8.2.12 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2023 21:15:15) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.12, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
probé con la instalacion de xdebug 8.2 TZS y el fichero incluirlo en la carpeta de xampp\php\ext, pero sigue sin funcionar

¿Qué significa "no funciona"? ¿Qué hace/no hace?
